# Action in controller not accepting arithmetic operators

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view with a table and for each row I have a button to allow you to move said row up by one notch. I have created an action in my controller called *order_up* to carry out such a method.

```
# steps_controller.rb
def order_up
  @users = User.all
  @project = Project.find(3)
  @soriginalorder = :order
  @scounter = 0

  @project.steps.each do |step|
    @scounter = @scounter + 1
    if @scounter == @soriginalorder-1
      step.order = @scounter + 1
    end

    if @scounter == @soriginalorder
      step.order = @scounter-1
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the relevant portion of my view:

```
<% @step_list_order = 0 %>

<% @project.steps.each do |step| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <% @step_list_order = @step_list_order + 1 %>
        <% step.order = @step_list_order %>
        <%= step.order %>
        <span class="label label-warning"><%= "Step" %></span>
        <%= link_to step.description, edit_step_path(step) %>
        <%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up\"></i> Up"), order_up_step_path(step), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

I apologize for the unreadable variable names but underscores and arithmetic operators are giving me errors. Here's the one I'm getting with a "-" sign: ***undefined method `-' for :order:Symbol*** A different SO question suggested that things were not defined properly but it everything seems to have been called.

I appreciate any help that someone can provide. Also happy to update question with more code or any clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: What is this supposed to be? `@soriginalorder = :order` You cannot do a minus operation on a symbol.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize that might have been an issue. _:order_ is an attribute of the model, _step_. Basically, I am pulling the step's original order (i.e. placement) and putting that into the variable to keep track of it. This value is a positive integer and is defined upon creation of the step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add a integer (number) to a symbol `:order`. That does not work.

you have to change this line

```
@soriginalorder = :order
```

It's a bit hard to understand your logic, but you have to change `:order` into a integer

You can test this

```
@soriginalorder = 3
```

This should not give you the same error.

You can get this functionality from the [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem.

You should also check out this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists)

Comment: Made the change and no longer getting that error. Was going through it for awhile but thought it was something relating to me not knowing how the controller works. You saved me a lot of time and pain :) Thanks!

Comment: I'd advise `closure_tree` over `ancestry` -- which has proven to be very liberal with SQL queries. https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree appears to be focused on performance first.

Comment: @DamienRoche Thanks for sharing that gem. Already has the functions I was about to build out from scratch!